# $\frac {\partial}{\partial t}T$ vs $\frac d{dt} T$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

Suppose we have a function $T_1=F(x,y,t)$. Now suppose that $x=g(t),y=h(t)$, so we have a new $T_2=F(x(t),y(t),t)$, so then we have that $\frac \partial{\partial t} T_2=F_t$ and $\frac d{dt}T_2=F_x x_t+F_yy_t+F_t$.

My question is, if we let $x,y$ and $t$ be independant variables, does the symbol $\frac d{dt}T_1$ (if we use the same idea as before, we should have that $\frac d{dt}T_1=\frac {\partial}{\partial t}T_1$, is this true?) have any meaning?

Answer (score 1):

$F(x,y,t)$ is a function of three variables. So you can compute $F_x,F_y$ and $F_t$ (assuming they exist).

If $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ then $F(x(t),y(t),t)$ is a function of one variable: $t.$ You can compute its derivative $\frac{d}{dt}F$ using that chain rule. As you have said $$\dfrac{d}{dt}T=F_xx'+F_yy'+F_t.$$ So, if $x$ and $y$ are constant (don't depend on $t$) then

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}F=F_xx'+F_yy'+F_t=0F_x+0F_y+F_t=F_t=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F.$$

Going back to your question, $\dfrac{d}{dt}F$ is the derivative of a function of one variable and thus, if $x,y$ and $t$ are independent then $\dfrac{d}{dt}F$ makes no sense. $\dfrac{d}{dt}F$ can be thought as the derivative along a curve (or a directional derivative in the direction of the tangent of the curve). So, if $x,y$ and $t$ are independent then we don't have any given direction to get the derivative.